# Why does list :: element give an error?

Tags: scala

I'm new to scala and just playing around with it in my free time and ran into this problem:

if I have this list:

```
 val list = List(1,2,3,4)
```

and then say:

```
 val newList = list :: 5
```

scala tells me

```
 error: value :: is not a member of Int
```

but if I say:

```
 val newList = list ::: List(5)
```

scala is completely alright with it. **Why can I not append an element to a `List`, but I can append all elements of a `List` to the end of a `List`**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've got the syntax backwards:

```
5 :: list
```

This will prepend the element `5` to the front of `list`.

In Scala, operators that end with a colon (`:`) are right-associative.  So `5 :: list` calls the `::` method on `list` and gives the argument `5`.

The reason `list ::: List(5)` works is that it's actually prepending `list` to the front of `List(5)`.

By the way, `List` also has the operators `+:` and `:+` for prepend and append, respectively.  (But keep in mind that prepending to a `List` is O(1) while appending is O(n).)

Comment: ohhh alright so i was actually saying 5.::(list) ok. So that explains the error message then